# Building a killer script in bash

Tags: bash, while-loop, pipe, netstat

I've been trying to learn the syntax of logic statements in bash, how to do if/else, pipes and stuff. I'm trying to build a bash script, but I fail miserably after 3 hours of not getting how this stuff works.

Now I need this little script, I'll try to explain it using a generalized code, or call it whatever you want. Here you go:

```
while variable THRESHOLD = 10

{
if netstat -anltp contains a line with port 25565
then set variable THRESHOLD to 0 and variable PROCNUM to the process number,
else add 1 to variable THRESHOLD
sleep 5 seconds
}
kill the process No. PROCNUM
restart the script
```

Basically, what it does is, that once the socket closes, after a few tries, it kills the process which was listening on that port.

I'm pretty sure it's possible, but I can't figure out how to do it properly. Mostly because I don't understand pipes and am not really familiar with grep. Thank you for your help, in advance.

Comment: what's to understand about pipes? they take the output from one program and feed it as input to another.

Comment: Oh. Well that feels awkward. What if I want to feed it to a binary as a specific argument? Let's say
binary -a passedtext OR 
binary -d passedtext -a somethingelse
?

Comment: use `xargs`: it takes the data being piped in and feeds to a specified app as command line arguments. e.g. `echo 'somefile.txt' | xargs rm -f` will actually execute `rm -f somefile.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't want be offensive, but if you can write a "generalized" program all you need is learn th **syntax** of the `while`, `if` for bash and read the man pages of the `grep` and `kill` and so on...

And the `pipes` are the same as in your garden. Having two things: `tap` and `pond`. You can fill your pond with many ways (e.g. with rain). Also, you can open your tap getting water. But if you want fill the pond with the water from a tap, need a pipe. That's all. Syntax:

```
tap | pond
```

- the output from a tap
- connect with a pipe
- to the (input) of the pond

e.g.

```
netstat | grep
```

- the output from a `netstat`
- connect with a pipe
- to the input of the `grep`

that's all magic... :)

About the syntax: You tagged your question as `bash`.

So googling for a `bash while syntax` will show to you, this Beginners Bash guide

```
http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_02.html
```

to, and you can read about the `if` in the same website.

Simply can't believe than after 3 hours you cannot understand basic `while` and `if` syntax to write your program with a bash syntax - especially, when you able write an "generalized" program...

is is not to hard (with modifying the 1st example in the above page) to write:

```
THRESHOLD="0"
while [ $THRESHOLD -lt 10 ]
do
    #do the IF here
    THRESHOLD=$[$THRESHOLD+1]
done
```

and so on...

Answer (score 1):

```
    #!/bin/bash
    # write a little function
    function do_error {
        echo "$@" 1>&2
        exit 1
    }
    # make the user pass in the path to the executable
    if [ "$1" == "" ]; then
        do_error "USAGE: `basename $0` <path to your executable>"
    fi
    if [ ! -e $1 ]; then
        do_error "Unable to find executable at $1"
    fi
    if [ ! -x $1 ]; then
        do_error "$1 is not an executable"
    fi
    PROC="$1"
    PROCNAME=`basename $PROC`

    # forever
    while [ 1 ]; do
        # check whether the process is up
        proc=`ps -ef | grep $PROCNAME 2>/dev/null`
        # if it is not up, start it in the background (unless it's a daemon)
        if [ "$proc" == "" ]; then
            $PROC &
        fi
        # reinitialize the threshold
        threshold=0
        # as long as we haven't tried 10 time, continue trying
        while [ threshold -lt 10 ]; do
            # run netstat, look for port 25565, and see if the connection is established. 
            # it would be better to checks to make sure
            # that the process we expect is the one that established the connection
            output=`netstat -anp | grep 25565 | grep ESTABLISHED 2>/dev/null`
            # if netstat found something, then our process was able to establish the connection
            if [ "$output" != "" ]; then
                threshold = 0
            else
                # increment the threshold
                threshold=$((threshold + 1))
            fi
            # i would sleep for one second
            sleep 1
        done
        kill -9 $PROCNUM
    done
```

Comment: Oh my god. THANK YOU. SO MUCH. In 19 lines. I love you.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't actually run this, so if you encounter any errors you can let me know and I'll fix them.